# Automatic network discovery of devices in java

Tags: java, network-programming, osgi, soa, network-protocols

First i wish to declare that i am not asking any code for my question or asking some one to do my project.All i need some suggestions and references to my questions to start cording

I was asked to write some automatic discovery mechanism of smart devices.Each devices must discover automatically themselves.I have some suggestions about zero config libraries,Upnp standards. I was also asked to use R-OSGI in Java to Develop a service based component for this senario.I am pretty confuse in following stuffs,

- Even though if i use these libraries,Where i need to write a
  component and its services?
- Eg.I have smart phone and smart TV.So how i connect these using these
  libraries?Do i need a router and deploy my component at router to discover both
  devices?or if i deploy  component in both devices,will they connected
  via wireless adapter?I am confuse that how this model will be?
- Also are there any simple alternative for zero config libraries?I am
  using Java and R-OSGI.If any libraries exist can any one suggest name
  and some references for that?
- If zero config is easiest than these can any one suggest any book
  name for zero config libraries?

Answer (score 1):

[R-OSGi](http://r-osgi.sourceforge.net/) came with a related project called [jSLP](http://jslp.sourceforge.net/). Both should now be available via the [Eclipse Communication Framework](http://www.eclipse.org/ecf/).

[SLP](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Service_Location_Protocol) in general can be used to discover services (software and/or hardware) in the local network.

You might want to read up on how to integrate jSLP to answer some of your questions.

Comment: Thank you very much at least for a starting point.I will read and come back with doubts:)